# Why is the Databricks notebook cell training my ML model "Running command..." forever?

Tags: python, pytorch, azure-databricks, mlflow, pytorch-lightning

I am training PyTorch models on a Azure Databricks cluster (on a notebook), using PyTorch Lightning, and doing the tracking using mlflow.

I would like to store training metrics + artifacts on the Databricks-hosted tracking server.

To enable that, code is as follows:

```py
mlflow.pytorch.autolog()
trainer = pl.Trainer(gpus=1, max_epochs=30, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience = 6)], progress_bar_refresh_rate=0)
trainer.fit(classifier, train_dl, valid_dl)
print("Done")
```

However, the notebook cell gets stuck in a "Running command..." state for way too long:

[image: Running forever]

even though in the driver logs execution seems to have ended:

[image: Run is over]

and the experiment is marked as FINISHED in the mlflow UI:

[image: mlflow tracking]

Stopping execution manually doesn't solve either, as the cell would stay in a "Cancelling..." state forever. So the only option left is to clear the cluster state.

This is a problem because I can't execute further commands that would be useful for artifact logging:

```py
mapping.to_json("/tmp/mapping.json", orient = "records")
mlflow.log_artifact("/tmp/mapping.json", "mapping")

torch.save(classifier.state_dict(), "/tmp/model.pt")
mlflow.log_artifact("/tmp/model.pt", "model.pt")
```

This problem seems to correlate with GC problems:

> 2021-04-22T07:58:58.025+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen:
> 28399104K->100290K(28499456K)] 28696488K->397698K(85935104K),
> 0.0755720 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.06, real=0.08 secs]  2021-04-22T08:01:01.645+0000: [GC (System.gc()) [PSYoungGen:
> 4522724K->54360K(28561920K)] 4820132K->351776K(85997568K), 0.0237712
> secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs]
> 2021-04-22T08:01:01.669+0000: [Full GC (System.gc()) [PSYoungGen:
> 54360K->0K(28561920K)] [ParOldGen: 297416K->123173K(57435648K)]
> 351776K->123173K(85997568K), [Metaspace: 203356K->203325K(219136K)],
> 0.3513905 secs] [Times: user=0.99 sys=0.00, real=0.36 secs]

Am I doing something wrong? Should I track experiments + artifacts in another way? Running neither single-node nor cluster works, nor reducing the size of the training set.

Comment: Hi Davide, any updates on this?

Comment: Yes please, let me know!

Comment: See related question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183733/databricks-notebook-hanging-with-pytorch/72473053#72473053