# Databricks notebook hanging with pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, databricks, torch

We have a Databricks notebooks issue. One of our notebook cells seems to be hanging, while the driver logs do show that the notebook cell has been executed. Does anyone know why our notebook cell keeps hanging, and does not complete? See below the details.

**Situation**

- We are training a ML model with *pytorch* in the Databricks notebook UI
- The training uses *mlflow* to register a model
- At the end of the cell we print a statement "Done with training"
- We are using a single node cluster with

  - Databricks Runtime: 10.4 LTS ML (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, GPU, Scala 2.12)
  - Node type: Standard_NC6s_v3

**Observations**

- In the Databricks notebook UI we see the cell running *pytorch* training and showing the intermediate logs of the training
- After awhile the model is registered in *mlflow* but we don't see this log in the Databricks notebook UI
- We can also see the print statement "Done with training" in the driver logs. We don't see this statement in the Databricks notebook UI

**Code**

```
from pytorch_lightning import Trainer
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks.early_stopping import EarlyStopping

trainer = Trainer(gpus=-1, num_sanity_val_steps=0, logger = logger, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor="test_loss", patience = 2, mode = "min", verbose=True)])

with mlflow.start_run(experiment_id = experiment_id) as run:
  trainer.fit(model, train_loader, val_loader)
  mlflow.log_param("param1", param1)    
  mlflow.log_param("param2", param2)    
  mlflow.pytorch.log_model(model._image_model, artifact_path="model", registered_model_name="image_model")
  mlflow.pytorch.log_state_dict(model._image_model.state_dict(), "model")
  
print("Done with training")
```

**Packages**

```
mlflow-skinny==1.25.1
torch==1.10.2+cu111 
torchvision==0.11.3+cu111
```

**Solutions that I tried that did not work**

- Tried adding cache deletion, but that did not work

```
# Cleaning up to avoid any open processes...  
del trainer
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
# force garbage collection
gc.collect()
```

- Tried forcing exiting the notebook, but also did not work

```
parameters = json.dumps({"Status": "SUCCESS", "Message": "DONE"})
dbutils.notebook.exit(parameters)
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the issue. To solve this, adjust the parameters for the `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`

1. Disable `pin_memory`
2. Set `num_workers` to 30% of total vCPU (e.g. 1 or 2 for Standard_NC6s_v3)

For example:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(
    train_dataset,
    batch_size=32,
    num_workers=1,
    pin_memory=False,
    shuffle=True,
)
```

This issue seems to be related to PyTorch and is due to a deadlock issue. See the [details here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html#avoiding-and-fighting-deadlocks).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72473053/10555941

There is more to add to the above answer. When you set pin_memory True and have num_workers equal to the total number of vCpus on the node, it uses IPC for the threads to communicate. These IPC's use shared memory and they suffocate the shared memory of VM.

This leads to the hanging of the processes. The DataLoader num_workers is just to help in data loading using child threads. That said it need not be an extreme value to speed up data-loading. Having it small like 30% of vCPUS would suffice for data loading.